# Combine pcl_ros with standalone pcl

Tags: rviz, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I would like to send to RViz my PointCloud2 data yet I'm running the standalone PCL. It would be possible to use the features from both pcl's in the same time? In case of the usage of standalone PCL there is no need to specify the dependency in the manifest.xml, how it would be in case if both packages installed?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10984/combine-pcl_ros-with-standalone-pcl/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You really don't want to use standalone PCL inside ROS, as you can quickly run into issues since standalone PCL carries it's own copies of several ROS messages. If you can live with those features found in PCL 1.1 (minus the KinectGrabber), you should use the version of PCL found within the ROS Electric release (by depending on the ROS package "pcl").

If you need some feature found in PCL trunk, there may not be a very clean way to use it within ROS currently.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3